# Rails remove duplicated associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Let's say I have a `User` and User `has_many :tags` and I would like to remove all `@users` tags that have duplicated `name`. For example,

```
@user.tags #=> [<Tag name: 'A'>, <Tag name: 'A'>, <Tag name: 'B'>]
```

I would like to keep only the tags with unique names and delete the rest from the database.

I know I could pull out a list of unique tags names from user's tags and remove all users's tags and re-create user's tags with only unique names but it would be ineffficient?

On the other hand, `select` won't work as it returns only the selected column. `uniq` also won't work:

```
@user.tags.uniq #=> returns all tags
```

Is there a more efficient way?

UPDATE:
I would like to do this in a migration.

Comment: you want to remove duplicated or to show the tags only once?

Comment: Which DB are you using? On Postgres you could use something like `SELECT  DISTINCT ON(tags.name) tags.id FROM "tags" GROUP BY "tags"."id", "tags"."user_id"`. Which will give you the unique tags. You can remove the others by using these ids in a `WHERE tags.id NOT IN ?`.

Comment: I am using Postgres.

Comment: @NEL I want to remove the associated duplicated records from the database.

Comment: @max how would I apply this in a migration?

Answer (score 3):

This method will give you an ActiveRecord::Relation with the duplicate tags:

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  def self.duplicate_tags
    unique = self.select('DISTINCT ON(tags.name, tags.user_id) tags.id')
     .order(:name, :user_id, :id)
    self.where.not(id: unique)
  end
end
```

Its actually run as a single query:

```
SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" 
WHERE "tags"."id" NOT IN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT ON(tags.name) tags.id 
  FROM "tags" GROUP BY "tags"."id", "tags"."user_id" 
  ORDER BY tags.name, tags.id)
```

You can remove the duplicates in a single query with [`#delete_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all).

```
# Warning! This can't be undone!
Tag.duplicate_tags.destroy_all
```

If you need to destroy dependent associations or call your `before_*` or `after_destroy` callbacks,  use the [`#destroy_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all) method instead. But you should use this together with [`#in_batches`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-in_batches) to avoid running out of memory.

```
# Warning! This can't be undone!
Tag.duplicate_tags.in_batches do |batch|
  # destroys a batch of 1000 records
  batch.destroy_all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write SQL model-independent query in the migration.
Here is PostgreSQL-specific migration code:

```
execute <<-SQL
  DELETE FROM tags
  WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON(user_id, name) id FROM tags
    ORDER BY user_id, name, id ASC
  )
SQL
```

And here is more SQL common one:

```
execute <<-SQL
  DELETE FROM tags
  WHERE id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t2.id FROM tags t1
    INNER JOIN tags t2
    ON (
      t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND
      t1.name = t2.name AND
      t1.id < t2.id
    )
  )
SQL
```

[This SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2QbQVbaioZf4eAwEpi9p5R/9) shows
different queries you can use as *sub-select* in `DELETE` query depending on your goals: deleting *first/last/all* duplicates.

Comment: Nice, I could use this solution if I have a join table in a `HABTM` relationship as well. Just a new `JOIN` and that's it.

Comment: @jedi Look at the fiddle, please. It shows, what duplicates will be deleted exactly. Also, it allows to try extra JOINS when you have `HABTM`.

Comment: The results in the fiddler don't look right. Both user 1 and 2 should have only one tag 'A' and one tag 'B'.

Comment: There are 5 different result in the fiddler with comments, which describes what exactly it returns.